# How do I echo out a day in the future using date()?

Tags: php, date

I want to always echo out the date 3 days from now. So right now I have:

```
$date = date("l F jS");
echo $date;
```

Which echos "Friday June 5th"

What exactly do I do so that it echos out "Monday June 8th" and tomorrow it echos out "Tuesday June 9th" (always 3 days ahead).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `strtotime()` with a [relative date format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php). When you pass a Unix timestamp as the second parameter to `date()` it will format that date.

```
$date = date("l F jS", strtotime('+3 days'));
echo $date;
```

Or if you prefer OOP use `DateTime()`. With `DateTime()` you can put the relative date format right into its constructor. It also handles things like daylight savings time which *may* come into play depending on what you're doing.

```
$date = new DateTime('+3 days');
echo $date->format("l F jS");
```

Comment: Ha, much better solution than mine, `echo date("l F jS", (time() + 86400 * 3));`

Comment: Awesome! Both work. Which one would you use? Let's say someone was looking over your code for a project. Which one shows better that you're a good coder? Or would it not matter since both do the same thing?

Comment: The second method is preferred. It takes things like DST into account and can be extended to work with timezones easier.